# How do I rework my code to avoid left shift warning?

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings

I have this method `read` meant to read an integer datatype from an address of an unsigned char pointer `data`. For example, if `data` contains `0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78, 0x9A`, `read<int>(1, ptrToMyInt)` should put `0x3456789A` into `ptrToMyInt`.

Example:

```cpp
class MyClass {
    public:
        MyClass();

        template <typename T> void read(int address, T *dest) {
            size_t size = sizeof(T);

            *dest = 0;

            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                *dest <<= 8;
                *dest |= data[address + i];
            }
        }

        static constexpr unsigned char data[] = { 0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78 };
}
```

When I use this template on an unsigned char pointer (for consistency's sake to avoid having multiple read methods), it gives a warning since the line `*dest <<= 8;` shifts more than the width of a byte, and the compiler isn't smart enough to realize that it only happens once when the byte is already 0.

For example:

```cpp
MyClass c;

unsigned char x;
c.read(2, &x); // warning: shift count >= width of type
               // should and does put 0x56 into x
```

[Demo](https://www.godbolt.org/z/PtHB3C)

I want to rework this code to avoid this warning, but I can't see a simple/elegant way of rewriting it. How should I rewrite this code?

Comment: `dest` isn't declared as a type

Comment: Please show a [mcve]

Comment: What do you mean by "address of a byte pointer" and what is "word"?   If you are using `std::byte` (from C++17) say so.   If you are using something else (which would be necessary before C++17  since `byte` is non-standard) say so.   Furthermore,  `word` is not a standard type in C++.    Also, try providing a [mcve] - in this case, a simple program that CALLS your read function in a way that demonstrates your problem, would suffice.

Comment: Why not just use `memcpy`?  Your whole function can be replaced with `std::memcpy(dest, data + address, sizeof(T));`

Comment: If you are absolutely sure that your code is solid you can opt to disable the specific warning.

Comment: @NathanOliver: depends of endianess...

Comment: @anastaciu - That normally means understanding the code well enough to know why the warning occurs AND to know that the code is correct.   The OP is not demonstrating that understanding.

Comment: @Jarod42 But that's what the OP code is doing, so that shouldn't be a concern.

Comment: I've fixed the question with all of your feedback. Sorry about the stuff with `word` (`int`) and `byte` (`unsigned char`) I had to remove a lot of project-specific typedefs and missed those

Comment: @Peter, yes, that should always be the case.

Comment: @Peter I know why the warning occurs and how the code works (I wrote it, I didn't just copy it from somewhere), I'm asking how to rewrite it so the warning doesn't occur.

Comment: @RK. pleas provide a [MCVE] (IOW something we can copy/paste/compile without guesswork. For example what is `MyClass`? What is `data`?

Comment: Use `*dest *= 256;` which is equivalent and avoids implementation defined behavior. (The warning is valid. There is no rule that says shifting 0 by larger than the data size must remain zero.)

Comment: @RK. Sorry, but your code ([or at least what I guess is your code](https://www.godbolt.org/z/YzYShL)) does not compile.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: With trivial typos fixed, (compile](https://www.godbolt.org/z/BK8Kgh) (but no warnings).

Comment: @NathanOliver: I disagree, `memset` can give `0x12345678` or `0x78563412` depending of endianess, with OP, it is necessary `0x12345678` (assuming same `data` input).

Comment: @Jarod42 actually I did not get any warnings with -Wall on one machine but did with the same compiler flags on another, something to do with clang vs g++ maybe?

Comment: @RK: indeed, warning with clang...

Comment: @RK - It's one thing to (claim you) understand why a warnng occurs and how the code works.   It's another to demonstrate that to others, when you are asking them to help you eliminate the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With C++17, you might do

```
template <typename T> void read(int address, T *dest) {
    constexpr size_t size = sizeof(T);

    if constexpr (size == 1)
    {
        *dest = data[address];
    } else {
        *dest = 0;

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            *dest <<= 8;
            *dest |= data[address + i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did not know about `constexpr`, thanks! What do you think about one commenter's idea of `*dest *= 256;`